# Multiprocessing Pipe() not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pipe

I am trying to get familiar with the `multiprocessing` module. I am currently having some issues with `Pipe()`. I devised a small example to illustrate my problem.

I wrote two functions:

- One that creates files in a specific folder (`spawner`)
- And another that detects these files and copies them to another folder (`cleaner`)

They both work fine. I also managed to create a `Process` for both so that the creation and copying of the files happens simultaneously.

For the next step, I want the `spawner` to communicate to the `cleaner` that it has finished creating files so that the latter can terminate.

Here is the code:

```
import os
from time import sleep
import multiprocessing as mp
from shutil import copy2


def spawner(f_folder, pipeEnd):
    template = 'my_file{}.txt'
    for i in range(10):
        new_file = os.path.join(f_folder, template.format(str(i)))
        with open(new_file, 'w'):
            pass
        sleep(1)
    pipeEnd.send(True)
    return


def cleaner(f_folder, t_folder, pipeEnd):
    state = set()
    while not pipeEnd.recv():
        new_files = set(os.listdir(f_folder)).difference(state)
        state = set(os.listdir(f_folder))
        for file in new_files:
            copy2(os.path.join(f_folder, file), t_folder)
        sleep(3)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    receiver, sender = mp.Pipe()
    from_folder = r'C:\Users\evkouni\Desktop\TEMP\PythonTests\subProcess\from'
    to_folder = r'C:\Users\evkouni\Desktop\TEMP\PythonTests\subProcess\to'
    p = mp.Process(target=spawner, args=(from_folder, sender))
    q = mp.Process(target=cleaner, args=(from_folder, to_folder, receiver))
    p.start()
    q.start()
```

I just cannot seem to be able to get it to work.. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A `Pipe` is the wrong solution to your problem. You could use a pipe if you wanted to pass the file names from the spawner to the cleaner, but what you are trying to do is raise a flag. For that purpose, I would recommend the use of an `Event`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Event

This can be considered a thread-safe (and multiprocess-safe) boolean. You would use it like

```
finished = mp.Event()
...
finished.set()  # pipeEnd.send(True)
...
while not finished.is_set():  # while not receiver.recv():
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It did work, more or less. Would you mind posting the `Pipe()` solution as well assuming i did want to pass the filenames?

Comment: In that case you would have `pipeEnd.send(new_file)` in the spawner (maybe sending `None` or `False` when finished). In the cleaner you would have `filename = pipeEnd.recv()`, then some simple text processing to generate the new name (in the dest dir), and `copy2(filename, dest_filename)`

Comment: Got it. I ended up doing it with `queue` (`put`ting files in the queue with `spawner` and `get`ting them with `cleaner` until `queue` is empty.) Thanks a lot!

Comment: A queue is even better in this case!

Comment: @Ixop Yeah, I figured that part out.